# SQL Server 2005 bigint missing?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am trying to set a column as a 64-bit integer, but my only available options are tinyint, smallint and int. Where did bigint run off to?

Notes: I'm using Access 2008 to access my SQL Server.

Comment: its called some_arbitrary_name_thats_inconsistent_between_versions_and_all_other_microsoft_technologies

Comment: @Andrew: Not really.  There's no BigInt equivalent in MSACCESS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with SQL Server. In SQL Server 2005, you can declare a column as bigint like so:

```
Create Table Table( Col1 bigint )
```

The problem is that MS Access does not recognize `bigint` as a data type.

Here's an [article](https://web.archive.org/web/20100730041916/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/access/archive/2009/06/10/handling-the-sql-server-bigint-data-type-in-access-2007-using-ado.aspx) on the problem which discusses some workarounds when using ADO. Here is [help article](https://web.archive.org/web/20131006160702/http://office.microsoft.com:80/en-us/access-help/about-differences-between-data-types-in-an-access-database-and-access-project-HP005274573.aspx) from Microsoft which states that Access still does not recognize bigint (see the section on *Comparison or mapping of data types between an Access database and Access project*).

Comment: Thanks, I figured it had something to do with using Access.

Answer (score 2):

Access 2007 does not have a bigint data type, which is why you're not seeing it as an available option.

If you need an integer that large, you can store it in a CURRENCY type (MONEY in SQL Server), and multiply or divide by 10000 to perform the conversion.

```
myCurrency = myBigInt / 10000

myBigInt = myCurrency * 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types?view=sql-server-ver16) comparing Access datatypes with their ODBC equivalents. No `bigint` there.

And here's an article called [Handling the SQL Server bigint data type in Access 2007 using ADO](https://web.archive.org/web/20100730041916/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/access/archive/2009/06/10/handling-the-sql-server-bigint-data-type-in-access-2007-using-ado.aspx) which offers two approaches to handling this: **convert the bigints to varchars or variants**. Sure, those make you queasy, but they sound like they might handle your problem.